# She calls me by

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-usage, grammaticality

Which one is correct?

She calls me by Disney princes’ names

Or

She calls me Disney princes’ names?

Comment: Both are grammatical. You might be pleased with one and offended by the other.

Comment: I really don't think the apostrophe (or the plural) should be there. Unless the meaning is something different than I assume it is, it's a simple singular attributive use: *Disney **prince** names*.

Comment: We wouldn’t use the apostrophe because there’s no possession?

Answer (score 1):

Call used with *by* is used when the calling action specifies the person:

*She calls me by my first name.*

*She uses my first name when talking about me or trying to get my attention.*

Call used without *by* is used to ascribe to a person certain qualities.

*She calls me Dr.Danger.*

*She ascribes the quality of bravery to me by using this name.*

This does not, of course, apply in every use of the word *call*, but for the example given and those like it.

Comment: So, when you’re calling someone nicknames you don’t use “by”; however, if you call someone by someone else’s name, you would use the “by”??????? E.g. “she calls me Disney prince names” “she called me by her guy friend’s name” (should I use the apostrophe there?)

Comment: Yes, that would be an accurate rule of thumb. The appostrophe is appropriate. From The Least You Can Do by Darryl Worley:   _Oh I know it won't be long till someone else is loving you
And waking up in your arms just the way that I used to
Promise me at least one time you'll call him by my name
And when I'm with somebody new I'll try to do the same_

Comment: I also wouldn't say that the two uses of _call_ are completely mutually exclusive, just that the one with _by_ is much more likely to be specifying and the one without ascriptive.